# Number of rows which will evaluate to be true

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic

### Question

> Consider the following well defined formula -:
>
> $$(p \vee q'\vee r' \vee s) \rightarrow t \vee u'$$

The maximum number of rows in truth table of above formula which evaluates to be true is?

### My Approach

\begin{align}\text{Let } Q &=(p \vee q' \vee r' \vee s) \rightarrow t \vee u' \\
&=(p \vee q' \vee r' \vee s)' + t + u' \\
&=p'qrs' + t + u'
\end{align}

$Q$ will always evaluates to be true except when all $p'qrs',t,u'$ will be false

I posted this question here because I think it as a question of combinatorics.

So the number of rows which will evaluate to be true=$$2^{3}-1=7$$

Am I correct?

Comment: There are 6 variables in $Q$.  The total number of rows of the truth table is $2^6=64$.

Comment: Strange it asks for the *maximum* number of rows, since that number is just plan *fixed*.

Comment: What does the nonlogical symbol + mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

There are $6$ variables, so $2^6=64$ rows

Any conditional is true iff either the antecedent is false or the consequent is true.

So, find all rows where the consequent $t \lor u'$ is true (this will be the case in $3$ out of $4$ cases, so out of the $64$, $48$ rows are like that)

Then find all the rows where the antecedent is false: this will be the case in $1$ pout of $16$ rows, i.e. out of $64$ rows, there are $4$ rows like that.

OK, so that seems to give $48 + 4 = 52$ rows .. but did you double count?  That is, in how many rows is the antecedent false *and* the consequent true? That number will need to be subtracted ... I'll leave that to you to figure out

Comment: sorry for being so late.Thanks for your solution! Sir, Rows that are double counted are when  antecedent being false $(1\text{ways})$ and consequent being true $(3\text{ways})$ i.e $1 \times 3=3$ i.e final answer should be $52-3=49$

Comment: @laura Correct! :)